# How to join multiple XML elements based on condition

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0, soa

i have XMl file with below structure. Each PIX transaction has multiple PIX messages of. they are grouped based on transaction types. I got requirement to join PIX messages of two particular PIXTransactionTypes = 613|05 and 603|02.

```
<Message>
    <PIXTransactions>
        <PIXTransactionType>613|05</PIXTransactionType>
        <PIX>
            <Name>A</Name>
        </PIX>
    </PIXTransactions>
    <PIXTransactions>
        <PIXTransactionType>603|02</PIXTransactionType>
        <PIX>
            <Name>B</Name>
        </PIX>
        <PIX>
            <Name>C</Name>
        </PIX>
        <PIX>
            <Name>D</Name>
        </PIX>
    </PIXTransactions>
    <PIXTransactions>
        <PIXTransactionType>602|02</PIXTransactionType>
        <PIX>
            <Name>F</Name>
        </PIX>
        <PIX>
            <Name>G</Name>
        </PIX>
        <PIX>
            <Name>G</Name>
        </PIX>
    </PIXTransactions>
</Message>
```

My resulting XML should be

```
<Message>
    <PIXTransactions>
        <PIXTransactionType>613|05</PIXTransactionType>
        <PIX>
            <Name>A</Name>
        </PIX>
        <PIX>
            <Name>B</Name>
        </PIX>
        <PIX>
            <Name>C</Name>
        </PIX>
        <PIX>
            <Name>D</Name>
        </PIX>
    </PIXTransactions>
    <PIXTransactions>
        <PIXTransactionType>602|02</PIXTransactionType>
        <PIX>
            <Name>F</Name>
        </PIX>
        <PIX>
            <Name>G</Name>
        </PIX>
        <PIX>
            <Name>G</Name>
        </PIX>
    </PIXTransactions>
</Message>
```

how do i achieve this in XSLT 1.0 or 2.0 ?

Comment: Why are the `PIX` elements in the input of `<PIXTransactionType>603|02</PIXTransactionType>` mapped in the output to `<PIXTransactionType>613|05</PIXTransactionType>`?

Answer (score 0):

For your particular goal you can use `copy-of` with predefined parameters as `param.pix.from` and `param.pix.to`, as in XSL below:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml"/>
    <!--define parameters FROM and TO-->
    <xsl:param name="param.pix.from" select="'603|02'" />
    <xsl:param name="param.pix.to" select="'613|05'" />
    <!--copy required PIXs to matched PIXTransactions block-->    
    <xsl:template match="PIXTransactions[PIXTransactionType = $param.pix.to]">
        <xsl:element name="{name()}">
            <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>                
            <xsl:copy-of select="/Message/PIXTransactions[PIXTransactionType = $param.pix.from]/*[name() = 'PIX']"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    <!--exclude required PIXTransactions from where PIXs blocks were taken-->
    <xsl:template match="PIXTransactions[PIXTransactionType = $param.pix.from]"/>
    <!--copy all nodes and attributes-->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Result as expected:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Message>
    <PIXTransactions>
        <PIXTransactionType>613|05</PIXTransactionType>
        <PIX>
            <Name>A</Name>
        </PIX>
        <PIX>
            <Name>B</Name>
        </PIX>
        <PIX>
            <Name>C</Name>
        </PIX>
        <PIX>
            <Name>D</Name>
        </PIX>
    </PIXTransactions>

    <PIXTransactions>
        <PIXTransactionType>602|02</PIXTransactionType>
        <PIX>
            <Name>F</Name>
        </PIX>
        <PIX>
            <Name>G</Name>
        </PIX>
        <PIX>
            <Name>G</Name>
        </PIX>
    </PIXTransactions>
</Message>
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that `Message` element always contains
`PIXTransactions/PIXTransactionType` = `613|05`,
the task can be performed as follows:

1. Create a template matching `PIXTransactions` containing
   `PIXTransactionType` = `613|05`. It should:

   - copy the own opening tag (`<xsl:copy>`),
   - copy its own content (you don't even need `apply-templates`
     to its children, ordinary `copy` will be quicker),
   - copy only `PIX` elements from sibling `PIXTransactions` element
     containing `PIXTransactionType` = `603|02`
   - copy the own closing tag (`</xsl:copy>`).
2. Create another template matching `PIXTransactions` containing
   `PIXTransactionType` = `603|02`, with empty content, to block its
   processing.
3. The last required script fragment is the *identity template*.

So the whole script can look like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="PIXTransactions[PIXTransactionType = '613|05']">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:copy-of select="node()"/>
      <xsl:copy-of select="../PIXTransactions[PIXTransactionType = '603|02']/PIX"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="PIXTransactions[PIXTransactionType = '603|02']"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

It works also in **XSLT 2.0**.